# Byte Array not printing to file correctly

Tags: java, file, split, arrays

I'm creating a program that aims to take in *n* number of splits and split a file into that amount of sub-files. In my **SplitFile.java**, I'm reading a file, passing an array of substrings that show the text that's supposed to go in each split file. I then convert the string into a byte array and write the byte array to the split file, but each file I'm creating is outputting something **just** slightly different.

**SplitFile.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SplitFile 
{
    int numberOfSplits = 1;
    File file;
    String[] parts = new String[5];

    public SplitFile(File file,int numberOfSplits)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.numberOfSplits = numberOfSplits;
    }

    public void FileSplitter() throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        String fileText = readFile();

        if(numberOfSplits == 2)
        {
            int mid = fileText.length() / 2;

            parts[0] = fileText.substring(0, mid);
            parts[1] = fileText.substring(mid);
        }
        else if(numberOfSplits == 3)
        {
            int third = fileText.length() / 3;
            int secondThird = third + third;

            parts[0] = fileText.substring(0, third);
            parts[1] = fileText.substring(third, secondThird);
            parts[2] = fileText.substring(secondThird);
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfSplits; i++)
        {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new fileInputStream(file));
            FileOutputStream out;
            String name = file.getName();

            byte[] b = parts[i - 1].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            int temp = 0;

            while((temp = bis.read(b)) > 0);
            {
                File newFile = new File(name + " " + i + ".txt");
                newFile.createNewFile();
                out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                out.write(b, 0, temp); // Writes to the file
                out.close();
                temp = 0;
            }

        }

    }

    public String readFile() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        try 
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            return sb.toString();
        }
        finally 
        {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

If I pass in 2 as the amount of splits I want, it is not splitting it right at the middle, with file 1 being the first half and file 2 being the second half, and instead giving the end of the text file for both files. My problem seems to be here:

```
while((temp = bis.read(b)) > 0);
{
    File newFile = new File(name + " " + i + ".txt");
    newFile.createNewFile();
    out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    out.write(b, 0, temp); // Writes to the file
    out.close();
    temp = 0;
}
```

An example file I'll use on here is this file:

**myFile.txt**

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

It splits into two files that go as follows:

**myFile.txt 1**

> nopqrstuvqxyz

**myFile.txt 2**

> opqrstuvqxyz

Any idea on what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your code, you define `File newFile = new File(name + " " + i + ".txt");` and `out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);` in whilte loop, it's not correct.
2. `while((temp = bis.read(b)) > 0);` not semicolon here =.="
3. Many mistake in your code
   I will change your code like:

   ```
           File newFile = new File(name + " " + i + ".txt");
           newFile.createNewFile();
           out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
           out.write(b); // Writes to the file
           out.flush();
           out.close();
   ```

If you need your code run as you want, here you are

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfSplits; i++) {
            String name = file.getName();
            byte[] b = parts[i - 1].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);

            int temp = 0;
            File newFile = new File(name + " " + i + ".txt");
            newFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);                    
            while ((temp = bis.read()) > 0)
            {
                out.write(temp); // Writes to the file
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But wow... Out of the things I tried, I didn't even consider those two lines as the biggest culprit of my problem. Your help was much appreciated.